# How to exit from a background thread loop?

Tags: c++, multithreading, stl, condition-variable, stdthread

I have a background thread for uploading files.  It runs in a loop; it does some work, then sleeps until a timeout elapses or until it is explicitly notified via a condition variable that there is more work to do. The problem is that sometimes I'm unable to get the thread to exit quickly.

Here is a simplified version:

```
    std::thread g_thread;
    std::mutex g_mutex;
    std::condition_variable g_cond;
    bool g_stop = false;

    void threadLoop()
    {   
        while (!g_stop)
        {   
            printf("doing some stuff\n");
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(g_mutex);
            g_cond.wait_for(lock, std::chrono::seconds(15));
        }   
    }   

    int main(int argc, char* argv[])
    {           
        g_stop = false;
        g_thread = std::thread(threadLoop);

        printf("hello\n");

        g_stop = true;
        g_cond.notify_one();
        g_thread.join();
    }
```

When I run this test program, I would expect it to exit quickly, but sometimes it gets stuck in the wait_for().  I think maybe the notify_one() is happening before the thread is sleeping in the wait_for(), but after the check of g_stop.

Is there a simple solution to this, or another design pattern that would work better?

Comment: You should change the type of g_stop to `atomic_bool` to avoid **undefined behaviour**, nevermind issues with caching. Or only read it while holding the mutex lock.

Comment: I'm not sure of the method in C++ but basically when a thread is in sleep, the only way to make it respond is to send a signal.
In C, it will be using `int pthread_kill(pthread_t thread, int sig)`;

Comment: @AxFab, no, that's not helpful. It's waiting on the condition variable, so you unblock it by notifying that condition variable.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Yes, you have to set `g_stop = true`. But if you want to quit before the 15 seconds of waiting you got to send a signal too.

Comment: @AxFab, no, that's nonsense. `g_cond.notify_one();` will wake it up. It's very similar to `pthread_cond_wait` and `pthread_cond_signal`, and you don't use a signal with condition variables.

Comment: Ok, my bad, didn't saw this one, but notify_one() do exactly what I just say...

Comment: @AxFab, no, that's also nonsense. It doesn't use signals.

Comment: One big issue is that proper use of condition variables arn't followed. You need to check for a predicate while holding the mutex (such as "is there work to do" or "should I stop") and then wait_for() if the predicate is false. Condition variables doesn't stay signaled, so if someone calls .notify() when you're not in the .wait_for() call - you miss the notification.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are reading and writing the `g_stop` variable without any synchronisation (such as using atomic operations, or using a mutex to serialize accesses to it). That is a data race, which is undefined behaviour.

Because you don't access it safely the compiler is allowed to assume that no other thread ever modifies `g_stop`, so in the `threadLoop` function it can load it into a register once and then never read the variable again, but just keep looping.

To ensure the write to the variable is seen by the looping thread you should use `std::atomic<bool>` or lock the mutex before all reads/writes to that variable. If you use an `atomic<bool>` that will fix the undefined behaviour, but doesn't ensure the thread will not wait on the condition variable, because as you suggest there is a window between checking the value of `g_stop` and going to sleep, in which the main thread can set `g_stop = true` and signal the condvar, so the looping thread doesn't wait until after the notify_one() call, and so misses it.

This slightly changed version will ensure that the thread will not wait on the condition variable if the main thread has told it to stop:

```
std::thread g_thread;
std::mutex g_mutex;
std::condition_variable g_cond;
bool g_stop = false;

void threadLoop()
{   
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(g_mutex);
    while (!g_stop)
    {   
        printf("doing some stuff\n");
        g_cond.wait_for(lock, std::chrono::seconds(15));
    }   
}   

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{           
    g_stop = false;
    g_thread = std::thread(threadLoop);

    printf("hello\n");

    {
      std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(g_mutex);
      g_stop = true;
    }
    g_cond.notify_one();
    g_thread.join();
}
```

This works because the looping thread holds a lock on the mutex while it checks `g_stop`, and it keeps holding that lock until it starts to wait on the condvar. The main thread takes the lock to set `g_stop = true`, which it can only do while the other thread is waiting.

This means there are only two possible executions now. `g_stop = true` happens while the thread is waiting on the condvar, and either it wakes up just before the notify_one() call or it wakes up *because* of the notify_one() call, but in both cases it will see `g_stop == true` immediately and stop looping.

Comment: Ah; I didn't realize that wait_for() would release the lock.  This makes sense to me.  Thanks!

Point taken about the atomicity of g_stop... I was assuming that aligned accesses of bools would be atomic by default on most architectures; is that a reasonable assumption? (Even so, there's no harm in using atomic<bool> instead, and I will.)

Comment: Also.. curious, why did you choose lock_guard instead of unique_lock in your code?

Comment: Yes, waiting on a condition variable releases the lock and goes to sleep. And it does so atomically, so there's no chance of the main thread re-locking the mutex, setting `g_stop=true` and sending the notification between the unlock and the wait. That means you won't miss the notification ... as long as the condition being waited for (in this case the boolean becoming true) happens under the protection of the same mutex as the condition variable waits on. This is part of what @nos referred to in the comment above about using a condition variable properly.

Comment: It's probably safe to assume that aligned 1-byte accesses are atomic but that's not all you need to worry about. Using proper atomic operations takes care of memory visibility and synchronisation, not just ensuring no partial reads/writes. Finally, I used `lock_guard` in the main thread because it's simpler than `unique_lock` and so (very slightly) faster. A `unique_lock` can be unlocked/relocked during its lifetime, which is necessary to use it with a `condition_variable`, but is not necessary in the main thread where you just want to lock it on construction and unlock on destruction.